# MySql: Stored Procedure for split, return table

Tags: mysql

I found a lot of examples of split-procedures for MySql returning the xth-part of a string. But I need a split-procedure to return ALL parts of a splitted string, so someling like:

```
SELECT split(",", "1,2,3,4,5,6");
```

Should return;

```
+-------+
| split |
+-------+
|     1 |
|     2 |
|     3 |
|     4 |
|     5 |
|     6 |
+-------+
```

I tried:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `split`(delimeter VARCHAR(1),txt VARCHAR(65535))
RETURNS split TABLE (
  part varchar(1024) NOT NULL)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

DECLARE pos, posOld;

set pos := locate(delimeter,txt);
set posOld = 1;

WHILE pos > 0 DO
 set part := subst(text, posOld, pos-1);
 set posOld := pos+1;
 insert into split (`part`) values (part);

 set pos := locate(delimeter, txt, posOld);
END WHILE;

END$$
```

but get the error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'split TABLE (part varchar(1024) NOT NULL)
```

Whats the correct way to do it?

Comment: You are mixing up procedures and functions - procedures do not have RETURNS and mysql does not support table valued functions.

Comment: That will never work like you would want it to work.. stored procedure can not be called with a SELECT you need to use CALL ... a function can be made that work on select but can't return multiple records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with plain SQL only. 
 
This trick is by using a MySQL number generator in combination with nested SUBSTRING_INDEX functions.

**Query**

This query will generate numbers from 1 to 100. 
So the final query can support up to 100 separated values.

```
SELECT 
 (@number  := @number + 1) AS number
FROM (
  SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
) AS record_1
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
) AS record_2
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @number := 0 ) AS init_user_param
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c314ca/5

Now we are going to extract the values from the comma separated string with

**Query**

Replace [position] with a number from 0 - 5 which value you want to extract from the comma separated string.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('1,2,3,4,5', ',', [position]), ',', -1) AS split;
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c314ca/16

Now we know the basics we are going to combine both queries to a working solution.

**Query**

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@CSV, ',', generator.number), ',', -1) AS split
FROM (

  SELECT 
   (@number  := @number + 1) AS number
  FROM (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) AS record_1
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) AS record_2
  CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @number := 0 ) AS init_user_param
) 
 AS generator
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT @CSV := '1,2,3,4,5'
) AS init_user_param
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c314ca/20